# Can't install trigger network automation tools

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, triggers

I read in the howto documentation to [install Trigger](http://trigger.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html), but when I test in python environment, I get the error below:

```
>>> from trigger.netdevices import NetDevices
>>> nd = NetDevices()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/trigger/netdevices/__init__.py", line 913, in __init__
    with_acls=with_acls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/trigger/netdevices/__init__.py", line 767, in __init__
    production_only=production_only, with_acls=with_acls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/trigger/netdevices/__init__.py", line 83, in _populate
    #    device_data = _munge_source_data(data_source=data_source)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/trigger/netdevices/__init__.py", line 73, in _munge_source_data
    #    return loader.load_metadata(path, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/trigger/netdevices/loader.py", line 163, in load_metadata
    raise RuntimeError('No data loaders succeeded. Tried: %r' % tried)
RuntimeError: No data loaders succeeded. Tried: [<trigger.netdevices.loaders.filesystem.XMLLoader object at 0x7f550a1ed350>, <trigger.netdevices.loaders.filesystem.JSONLoader object at 0x7f550a1ed210>, <trigger.netdevices.loaders.filesystem.SQLiteLoader object at 0x7f550a1ed250>, <trigger.netdevices.loaders.filesystem.CSVLoader object at 0x7f550a1ed290>, <trigger.netdevices.loaders.filesystem.RancidLoader object at 0x7f550a1ed550>]
```

Does anyone have some idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The NetDevices constructor is apparently trying to find a "metadata source" that isn't there.

Firstly, you need to [define the metadata](http://trigger.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/configuration.html#std:setting-NETDEVICES_SOURCE).  Second, your code should handle the exception where none is found.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the lead developer of Trigger. Check out the the doc [Working with NetDevices](http://trigger.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/netdevices.html). It is probably what you were missing. We've done some work recently to improve the quality of the setup/install docs, and I hope that this is more clear now!

If you want to get started super quickly, you can feed Trigger a [CSV-formatted NetDevices file](http://trigger.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/netdevices.html#csv-format), like so:

```
test1-abc.net.example.com,juniper
test2-abc.net.example.com,cisco
```

Just put that in a file, e.g. `/tmp/netdevices.csv` and then set the `NETDEVICES_SOURCE` environment variable:

```
export NETDEVICES_SOURCE=/tmp/netdevices.csv
```

And then fire up `python` and continue on with your examples and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

I found that the default of `/etc/trigger/netdevices.xml` wasn't listed in the setup instructions. It did indicate to copy from the trigger source folder:

```
cp conf/netdevices.json /etc/trigger/netdevices.json
```

But, I didn't see how to specify this instead of the default [`NETDEVICES_SOURCE`](http://trigger.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/configuration.html#std:setting-NETDEVICES_SOURCE) on the installation page.  But, as soon as I had a file that [`NETDEVICES_SOURCE`](http://trigger.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/configuration.html#std:setting-NETDEVICES_SOURCE) pointed to in my `/etc/trigger` folder, it worked.

I recommend this to get the verifying functionality examples to work right away with minimal fuss:

```
cp conf/netdevices.xml /etc/trigger/netdevices.xml
```

- Using Ubuntu 14.04 with Python 2.7.3